# How to change the Spring CacheManager dynamically?

Tags: spring-cache

I know a static way of using `CacheManager`.

```
@Cacheable(key = "'user'.concat(#userId).concat(#permission).concat(#user.userName)", cacheManager="UserCacheManager")
public boolean hasPermission(AppUser user, int userId, String permission) {
}
```

How can you dynamically change the `CacheManager` for user id starting with small letter and capital letter.

-- `SmallLetterCacheManager`
   -- `CapitalLetterCacheManager`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do in this case would be to always convert the `userId` (or perhaps `user.userName`) to lowercase and then cache that.  It is atypical for an application to both allow "`aSmith`" and "`asmith`" as 2 distinct, individual users.

However, if you must, and your application requirements are strict in this case, then you should have a look at `CacheResolver`, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-cache-resolver).  Also, see the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/CacheResolver.html).

Comment: Thaks for you help

Comment: John Blum: Please guide on this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316674/changing-cache-manager-for-child-method