# Changing cache manager for child method

Tags: spring-cache

```
@CacheConfig(cacheManager = ACacheManager, cacheNames = ACache)
class A {

    @Cacheable(key = "#user.userName", cacheManager="ACacheManager", cacheNames= {"ACache"})
    methodA (User user) {
    }
}


@CacheConfig(cacheManager = BCacheManager, cacheNames = BCache)
class B extends A {

    @Cacheable(key = "#user.userName", cacheManager="BCacheManager", cacheNames= {"BCache"})
    @Override
    methodA (User user) {
    }
}
```

`A a = new A();`
  `a.methodA();` Result should save in ACacheManager's cache ACache

`A b = new B();`
  `b.methodA();` Result should save in BCacheManager's cache BCache

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: -- First only one cache manager work on Spring Boot Application. If we start two cache manager. Then Spring Boot will complaint at run time. First how to resolve that? 

-- Second when Cacheable used in subclass. The run time run-time also complaint about it. How to resolve this?

-- Third if we resolve any how the two above issues. Will it be possible to achieve the below result? 
 
A a = new A();  a.methodA(); Result should save in ACacheManager's cache ACache

A b = new B();
b.methodA(); Result should save in BCacheManager's cache BCache

Comment: Are you sure you need two cache managers? Why are you repeating the information of the cache config in the cache annotation? If you have several cache managers you need to tell which one is the primary. You can flag it as @Primary or implement CachingConfig

Comment: My problem is simple that overridden method should use different cache manager. Please suggest how can be it achieved.